# Fixed a navbar from bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used the property `navbar-fixed-top` to fixed my navbar to the top. But I have an other fixed element we don't see.

This is my fixed navbar and under it, the fixed element I want to see.

[image]

What is happening is that my element (just call it "line") is fixed by the options but the position of the navbar is not absolute, so the line pass under the navbar and when I scroll down, the line is well fixed but it's hidden by the navbar. I don't know if it's clear but I want this two element to be glued and not superimposed.

How should I do ?

**EDIT :**

My jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5Zv8h/13/

If you try to remove th enavbar, you'll see that the first line stays on the top of the page. With the navbar, it's hidden.

Comment: Please share your code with us (more better JFiddle or Plunker) so we can see what your are doing at the moment.

Comment: your "line" needs to have a bit more space to the top since you fixed it with top: 0px; and you'll need something like top: 100px; and adjust it to the hight of the bootstrap navbar ;)

Comment: @Hammster I tried but it just make a marge between the navbar and the line. When I scroll, the line is still hidden by the navbar.

Comment: Please Lison, Can you create a fiddle ( exemple : bootply.com ) to reproduce your issue ? It will be more fast to help you with it, instead of guessing what there is on the picture....

Comment: @YenneInfo I'm trying to create one but I have some difficulties to do it ^^''

Comment: Don't worry, we'll wait for it, every senior developper begun by being beginer.

Comment: @YenneInfo Actually, I'm using Handsontable to create the line and I'm unable to add Bootstrap and handsontable at the same time in the jsFiddle.

Comment: You've got to add a margin to your second fixed div.
Look at [this](http://www.bootply.com/piHEExKn56) , look the margin-top in css area.

Comment: @YenneInfo Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/5Zv8h/13/ If you remove the navbar, you'll see that the first line of the grid stays on the top. But if you put the navbar, this line stays on the top but it's hidden by the navbar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88172/discussion-between-lison-and-yenne-info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written script to fix this, add this to Your code:

js

```
var navheight = $(".navbar-fixed-top").innerHeight();
var offtop = $(".ht_clone_top").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolltop + navheight >= offtop){
        if(!($(".ht_clone_top").hasClass("affixed"))){
            $(".ht_clone_top").addClass("affixed");
        }
        if(offtop>= scrolltop){
            console.log("now");
            $(".ht_clone_top").css({
                "top": scrolltop - 40
            });
        } else {
            $(".ht_clone_top").css({
                "top": 50
            });
        }
    } else {
        $(".ht_clone_top").removeClass("affixed");
        $(".ht_clone_top").css({
            "top": 0
        });
    }
});
```

css

```
.affixed {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
}
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/5r9p380n/2/